# How to setup header for all AJAX requests in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, csrf

jQuery has a simple and efficient way to setup a common header for all its AJAX requests.

And that is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

How can I do such a global setup in AngularJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to set header for whole the application via config app module.

```
var app = angular.module("auth", []);
// Configure auth app
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] =     $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}]);
// Parent controller
app.controller("auth", function ($scope) {
    // Your $http requests will have the common information above
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set headers in config of your app like Milad said or you can use the **http interceptor** concept.

Interceptor will be called whenever an http call is initiated and interceptor will run before the actual call processes.

```
angular.module('yourmodule').factory('httpRequestInterceptor',
['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
 {
  return {
   request: function($config) {
    if( $rootScope.user.loginticket )
    {
     $config.headers['your-auth-ticket'] = $rootScope.user.loginticket;
    }
  return $config;
  }
 };
}]);
```

And add this into app config:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
```